# Enable allow_url_fopen on cpanel

Tags: php, centos, cpanel, fopen

I have cPanel and I want enable `allow_url_fopen` on my host.
When I use this code

```
if (ini_get("allow_url_fopen") ==1) {
 echo "allow_url_fopen is ON";
 } else {
  echo "allow_url_fopen is OFF";
}
```

Show me

> allow_url_fopen is OFF

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP version is **under 5.4** you can use the following line of code to set **allow_url_fopen** to true.

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not enable fopen manually but instead use these commands on the terminal to install a package

Find the path of composer by running this command first:

```
$ which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

Install Package after that by using this path:

```
$ php -d allow_url_fopen=on /usr/local/bin/composer install package_name
```

OR

```
php -d allow_url_fopen=on `which composer` install package_name
```

Comment: ``php -d allow_url_fopen=on `which composer` install package_name`` also will work

Answer (score 0):

**How to enable or disable allow_url_fopen in cPanel**
There are certain scenarios when you may be asked to make changes to your PHP configuration. Specifically, you may be directed to edit a file on your server called php.ini, and to enable or disable allow_url_fopen.

While do not allow direct changes to PHP.ini on our servers. However, PHP configuration changes can be made from cPanel by following these steps:

1. Log into cPanel.
2. Look for the SOFTWARE section and click on Select PHP version: cPanel > Software > Select PHP Version
   [image]
3. In the new window click on the Switch To PHP Options link : Select PHP Version > Switch to PHP Options.
   [image]
4. Here you can locate the allow_url_fopen and tick on the box next to it to enable it or un-tick the box to disable it.
5. Once you’ll do any change, please do a left-hand side click anywhere outside the dropdown or text input box. If the change was successful, you will see a green box with a message which will confirm that the change has been applied.

That’s all! Now you know how to enable or disable allow_url_fopen in cPanel.