# Installing twilio package using composer

Tags: php, laravel, twilio-php

I have deployed a Laravel app in a shared host. I want to install package twilio and I get an error while installing using composer.

[image: Error message]

I think I cannot modify php.ini since I haven't given rights to edit php.ini file (cPanel).

Can you please suggest a way to get through this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605197/enable-allow-url-fopen-on-cpanel

Comment: @RavinderReddy Can I execute ini_set from command line and install twilio using composer? I think ini_set is a php command and should be run within a php script. I am not a master of PHP. Please do correct me.

Comment: You can use `-d` on commandline to set the value you need: http://php.net/manual/fr/features.commandline.options.php

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get through this by installing twilio in local server and then push all the modified files to the remote server. I had to manually merge the changes to the files in config folder. But it worked though it was a tedious task.